# Is there any way to show functions that are queued with setTimeOut() in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, settimeout

User login is managed with JWT stored in localStorage for my Website. 
And within login function, setTimeout function exists and it clears the localStorage, when token expiration time has come.
But It doesn't work when the device has been to sleep mode. When it awakes, the time of clearing localStorage has already passed and logout function is not being called as I expected.
So if there is some way to run the function that are queued with 'setTimeout()', I would like to call it when device is awake from sleep mode.

Is it possible to call the functions that already has passed the time of setTimeout?

Comment: That's very bad idea, your server should respond with 401 if token is expired and redirect user to signin page (use interceptors to do this). No need to clear localstorage.

Comment: @bogdanoff Yes, but I'm looking for the way to call the function queued with setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can save the timeout to a variable and check if it's been cleared, and manually call function as needed:

```js
const func = () => {
  console.log("hi")
}
const timeout = setTimeout(func, 1000)

// You'll have to implement a computer wake checker
onComputerWake(() => {
  if (!timeout) func()
})
```

But as another user mentioned in the comments, this is a terrible idea. JWTs have a built-in expiration. You should just have the server return 401, and redirect the user to the sign-in page if you receive 401 in your frontend.

Comment: So it's impossible to call setTimeout function manually... thanks. There are some APIs that should be able to call with and without token. If you load a tweet from twitter with token, you will see if you like the tweet or not. But if your token has expired, you don't really need to redirect users to login page. You can just simply show the tweet without 'like'. I already have 401 redirection logic in my interceptors for the APIs that should be only working with token. Thanks for answer.